# Open external link with parameters

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, hyperlink, url-parameters

I want to create a hyperlink or buttons that redirect user into an external website with parameters, looks something like this 'https://externalsite.com?param1=var1&param2=var2'. The problem is, if I copy the link to a browser, it works fine, but not when I click the link through hyperlink or buttons. All these only works on the Brave browser. It doesn't work on Chrome nor Firefox. What I mean by doesn't work is that the external shows an error page.

If it works normally, the page will take the values from the parameters and fill up some forms, and the final URL changed a bit, probably had gone a certain process. It could be the external site own problem but I want to diagnose it first on my part

Here is what I tried, simplified;

Hyperlink

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# makeURL(Eval("someID")) %>' Target="_blank">Proceed to External site</asp:HyperLink>
```

Or simply

```
<a href='<%# makeURL(Eval("someID")) %>' Target="_blank">To External</a>
```

Button

```
    <button OnClick="toExternal('<%# makeURL(Eval("someID")) %>')">Proceed to External site</button>

    <script>
    function toExternal(link)
    {
    x = confirm("To external link?");

    if (x)
    { open.window(link, '_blank') }
    }
    </script>
```

ASP button.

```
<asp:Button runat="server"  OnClientClick="toExternal('<%# makeURL(Eval("someID")) %>')" Text="To Extrernal" />
```

On inspection on the html source being generated, it looked something like the 1st hyperlink code, and when I copied into an empty html file and run, it worked. It just won't work pn Chrome/Firefox on an ASP page.

Edit:
Sample output from external page.

[image]

If it works, a form will appear, and fills up with information from the URL parameters.

Comment: Can you give your makeURL code and a sample output?

Comment: Please review the code ([MCVE] is a good guidance. Clearly `</script>` can't happen **inside** JavaScript function - looks like you incorrectly copy-pasted something when composing the question. (As of now it looks like typographical error)

Comment: Yes I must've mistyped it with the </script> tag. Corrected it. Edit the question with output sample, though I don't think it helps. I think the problem isn't the making of the URL, because I tested with hard code <a>, it works on simple html file, not in the aspx file.

Comment: Edit. My bad, the sample output you mean is probably look something like https://externalsite.com?param1=var1&param2=var2 like theone in the question (including the https://).

Comment: <asp:hyperlink
runat="server"
id="hlDividents"
navigateurl='<%# String.Format("TreatyRuleDetail.aspx?Rate={0}&Field2={1}&Field3={2}&Field4=something", Eval("Dividents"), Eval("Field2"), Eval("Field3")) %>'
text='<%# Eval("Dividents") %>'>
</asp:hyperlink>

Comment: I tried this, even hard-coded the value but it doesn't solve the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

I find out what the problem was. I never knew your server need to be white-listed by the other server in order to direct link it. We learned this after telling our client what was the problem.